# How to Get Content in text field dynamically, based on dropdown selection in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have two fields in database, one is package_title and another one is package_cost. I am Displaying package_title in drop down using while loop. When customer selects package_title from dropdown then i want to show its cost(package_cost) in another text field. Please help me.

my php code :

```
<div class="form-select-date">
    <div class="form-elements">
        <label>Select Package</label>
        <div class="form-item">
            <select>
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <?php
                $qry = "select * from `hajj_umrah_package`";
                $rec = mysql_query($qry );
                if( mysql_num_rows($rec) > 0)
                {
                    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($rec))
                    {
                        echo "<option value='".$res['id']."'>".$res['package_title']."</option>";
                    }
                } 
                ?> 
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-elements form-adult">
        <label>Price</label>
        <div class="form-item">
            <input type="text" name="cost"  />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add a ajax call on change of select option. In return you can get cost from a PHP file. and populate in the text box.

Comment: you can create a javascript array containing title as key and cost as value on selecting the title find the cost and show it to the input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as simple using jquery ajax. First you have to get the value of dropdown on change event of it. And then call ajax given below.

```
$('#dropdown_id').change(function(){
var package = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   data:{package:package},
   url:'get_cost.php',
   success:function(data){
       $('#cost').val(data);
   } 

});
```

});

Create one php file(get_cost.php) in same directory where you had written above code. In get_cost.php add following code :

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['package'])) {
    $qry = "select * from `hajj_umrah_package` where id=" . $_POST['package'];
    $rec = mysql_query($qry);
    if (mysql_num_rows($rec) > 0) {
        while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($rec)) {
            echo $res['package_cost'];
        }
    }
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: @MahmoodMohammed : Please Tick this answer as correct answer. As, it will solve other user to find it easily. Thanks.

Comment: @amit Chaudhari you just copy and paste others answer.it is your hobby ???? i saw your pervious answer and that was just copy and paste.

Comment: @amitchaudhary #dropdown_id & #cost comes from where ?

Answer (score 2):

Place your php query outside of your html body, and instead put it in the script tags of your header.

Then select both costs and titles into a json array.

Then populate your select dynamically using jquery when the page is loaded, and use jquery to watch for the change and grab the key from the select field and use it to populate the cost field with the associated cost key.

If you need to update the data periodically because the user may take longer than necessary on the page, you can add a loop to clear the prices data and repopulate without the user seeing.

This way the code can scale better, IMHO.

You can see an example here: [Populate text field based on result of dropdown selection - both with php mysql ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312164/populate-text-field-based-on-result-of-dropdown-selection-both-with-php-mysql)

[EDIT] Writing code for you:

```
<head><script>
var $list = array();

function loadData()
{
  //grab the data in function so it can also be recalled for updates if needed
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hajj_umrah_package";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  $list[$row['package_name']] = $row['package_price'];
}
echo '  $productVars = '.json_encode($list).';';
?>
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="packages" id="packages">
  <option data-price="" value='0'>Select...</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="textfieldid" id="textfieldid" value=""/>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {

    //first populate the drop down
    $.each($productVars, function(key, value)
    {   
       $('#packages')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",key)
         .data("price",value)
         .text(key)); 
    });

    //now watch for change
    $('select[name="packages"]').change(function()
    {
         $('#textfieldid').val($('select[name="packages"] option:selected').data('price'));
    });

  }
</script>
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 1):

you can Add ajax call on dropdown click and pass package value in search_cost php file then in search_cost.php file you can find pacakage cost then populated in the text box

```
 $('#dropdown_id').click(function(){
 var package = $('#dropdown_id').val();
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       data:{package:package},
       url:'search_cost.php',
       success:function(data){
           $('#cost').val(data);
      } 

      });

 });
```

search_cost.php

```
include("your connection file");

   $package=$_POST['package'];
   $query=("select cost from your_table_name where package_name='$package'");
   $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
   echo $row['cost'];
```

Comment: I would recommend against this.  That is a very expensive process for a static set of values.

Comment: @Lance please suggest simple proccess for this.

Comment: My answer is updated to show code below.  The reason I suggest a live request with every change is expensive is because an entire get has to be sent to the server to fetch the same data over and over, when once would do.

Comment: yes i agree with you @Lance. your process is much easy.