# Auto populate text fields based on dropdown selection where all values come from a MYSQL table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to auto populate some text fields (rate1 and rate2) based on a dropdown selection (instid and instfirstname). The values are all in one mysql table called tbl_insts. I'm trying the solution found in [How to Get Content in text field dynamically, based on dropdown selection in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102168/how-to-get-content-in-text-field-dynamically-based-on-dropdown-selection-in-php), but can't get it to work. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

This is my mysql table called tbl_insts

instid  instfirstname   rate1   rate2

1       john              50       45

2       eric               25       45

---

This is my html form. I'm able to populate the dropdown correctly but not the text fields.

```
<select name="instfilter" id="instfilter">
<?php
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("select instid, instfirstname from tbl_insts order by instid")) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($instid, $instfirstname);
    echo '<option value="-1" selected="selected">Please select...</option>';
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo '<option value="'.$instid.'">'.$instfirstname.'</option>';
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
</select>

<!-- Fields that I want to populate based on the selection on top -->
<input type="text" name="rate1" id="rate1" /> 
<input type="text" name="rate2" id="rate2" />
```

---

This is my code before the  tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$('#instfilter').change(function(){
var inst = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
data:{inst:inst},
url:'getrates.php',
success:function(data){
   $('#rate1').val(data);
   $('#rate2').val(data);
} 
});
});
</script>
```

---

This is my code in getrates.php in the same directory as the html file above.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['inst'])) {
    $qry = "select rate1, rate2 from tbl_insts where instid = ".
$_POST['inst'];
    $rec = mysql_query($qry);
    if (mysql_num_rows($rec) > 0) {
        while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($rec)) {
            echo $res['rate1'];
            echo $res['rate2'];
        }
    }
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: Make sure to mark one of these answers as correct if you believe they are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. try change data:{inst:inst} to data:{'inst':inst}
2. now you returning a string from getrates.php. From you code structure, you can do like this:

   ```
   if (mysql_num_rows($rec) > 0) {
       while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($rec)) {
           echo $res['rate1']."|".$res['rate2'];
       }
   }
   ```

..and

```
success:function(data){
 var inputs = data.split('|');
   $('#rate1').val(inputs[0]);
   $('#rate2').val(inputs[1]);
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks user2875204! It worked. I knew it was some JS syntax error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think these changes should do the job.

```
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($rec)) {
    $result = [
        'rate1' => $res['rate1'],
        'rate2' => $res['rate2']
    ];
}
.......
die(json_encode($result));
```

and

```
success: function(data){
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    $('#rate1').val(data.rate1);
    $('#rate2').val(data.rate2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! It worked. I knew it was some JS syntax error on my part.